# Using sended Email to change value on Object field

Tags: visualforce, field-update, site.com, developer

we are trying to send emails to customer where they can choose if they want to paticipate on an event or not.

If they choose "YES" or "NO" by klicking a link in sended email.
Salesforce should update the field  "STATUS" on a custom object with the value "YES" or "NO"

Is this accomplishable with Salesforce or do we need to get in touch with HUBSPOT e.g. ?

Thank you.
Best regards

Sebastian Röder

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of of doing this is to have a VF page hosted in Salesforce '[sites](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_overview.htm&language=en_US)' which takes some parameters e.g. emailaddress, item being Yes/No'd to and the Yes/No status. The controller of the VF page can then update Salesforce database as necessary.

In your email you'd just need a link e.g. http://mydomain.com?email=a@b.com&itemId=abc123&response=YES

Comment: Hi thankly for your quick answer.
what do you mean by "...item being Yes/No'd to and the Yes/No status" ?

Thank i will give it a shot.

Comment: Well, if I click on the link you need to know what I am agreeing to (item being Yes/No'd). If you know the Id then it would make sense to know if I am clicking YES or NO (Yes/No status). Simples.